# Maximum bound of expectation of product non-correlated in pairs random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

Random variables $X,Y,Z$ have $0$ expectation and variance $\sigma^2$. Also, they are not correlated in pairs. Find maximum and minimum of $\mathbb{E}XYZ$

1. $\operatorname{cov}XY,Z=\mathbb{E}XYZ-\mathbb{E}XY\mathbb{E}Z=\mathbb{E}XYZ$
2. By Coshi-Bynakovsky inequality $cov^2(XY,Z)\leq DXYDZ=\sigma^2DXY$
3. $DXY=\mathbb{E}X^2Y^2-(\mathbb{E}XY)^2=\mathbb{E}X^2Y^2-(\operatorname{cov}X,Y+\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y)^2=\mathbb{E}X^2Y^2$

But then I stucked. How can bound $\mathbb{E}X^2Y^2?$

Comment: Note that if $X=\pm\sigma$ with equal probability and $Y$ independently has the same distribution then $Z=XY/\sigma$ satisfies the conditions with $\mathbb{E}XYZ = \sigma^3$.  Similarly$Z=-XY/\sigma$ satisfies the conditions with $\mathbb{E}XYZ = -\sigma^3$.  So $\max \mathbb{E}XYZ \ge \sigma^3$ and  $\min \mathbb{E}XYZ \le -\sigma^3$, with the $\sigma^3$ in effect being a scaling factor.

Comment: @Henry thanks, I note this example too. But why it is bounds...